# IBM Mobile First IOS and Android private app store enquiry

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

Correct me if I am wrong.
For the private apps store, only intranet users able to download the apps.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5things/entry/5_things_to_know_about_ibm_worklight_application_center?lang=en
the above link show that the apps store and the files seems to be host in own premise.

Can users connect to public network or internet to download the setup files?

Can we host our apps store inside the premise but those binary data such as ipa and apk files is store outside of the premise or at other data center that have elastic network. And those contents can be managed by internal staff by internal network only. (In short is separate the binary files and the management web service server).

Sorry for my bad English.

Update:

For an example,
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/moving-production/distributing-mobile-applications-with-application-center/

Can we host our application store on-premises but those binaries (.ipa and apk files) locate in another data center which has elastic network? At the same time, those binaries can be managed by internal staff with internal/private network, such as publish or unpublish apk files etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn about IBM MobileFirst Platform Application Center visit:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/moving-production/distributing-mobile-applications-with-application-center/
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/c_intro_appcenter.html

> Correct me if I am wrong. For the private apps store, only intranet
>   users able to download the apps.

The purpose the Application Center is to act as an applications store, with similarities to stores such as Apple's App Store and Google Play (ranking, versioning, updates, and so on). Its main audience are enterprise users. Meaning, applications that are meant for internal use by company employees.

> Can users connect to public network or internet to download the setup
>   files?

Yes... to both.

The Application Center server is hosted by machines owned by the company, and can be available either only to the internal network or also to public Internet - depending on the needs of the application.
For example, if the client application is meant for field agents, but the customer prefers to serve the application via Application Center and not via the App Store/Google Play, then the Application Center server must be accessible via public Internet.

The MobileFirst Server hosts the .wlapp and .adapter files, and the Application Center server hosts the binaries - the .apk or .ipa files (instead of the App Store or Google Play).

> Can we host our application store on-premises but those binaries (.ipa
>   and apk files) locate in another data center which has elastic
>   network?

The binary files of the applications are stored in a database. Configure the Application Center to connect to your remote database and it should be fine.

> At the same time, those binaries can be managed by internal staff with
>   internal/private network, such as publish or unpublish apk files
>   etc...

Admins are defined in the server's server.xml; it's not related to anything asked.